# Real roots of the equation $2x^2+(4\sin\theta)x+\cos(2\theta)=0$

Tags: trigonometry, roots, discriminant, theta-functions

For what values of $\theta, 0 ≤ \theta ≤ 2π$ does the equation $$2x^2+(4\sin\theta)x+\cos(2\theta)=0$$ have real roots? Also, am I supposed to find specific values of $\theta$ or find an equation that makes $\theta$ all real roots?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As for all quadratic equations, the condition is the (reduced , here)  discriminant is non-negative:
$$\Delta'=4\sin^2\theta-2\cos 2\theta=2(1-\cos 2\theta)-2\cos 2\theta=2(1-2\cos 2\theta)\ge 0.$$
Can you solve the trigonometric inequation $\cos 2\theta\le\frac12$?

Answer (score 0):

Plug it into the quadratic formula.

$x = 2\sin\theta \pm \sqrt {4\sin^2\theta - 2\cos 2\theta}$

the roots are real if

$4\sin^2\theta - 2\cos 2\theta \ge 0\\
4\sin^2\theta - 2(1-2\sin^2\theta)\ge 0\\
8\sin^2\theta - 2\ge 0\\
|\sin\theta| \ge \frac 12\\
\frac {\pi}{6} \le \theta \le \frac {5\pi}{6}$ or
$\frac {5\pi}{6} \le \theta \le \frac {11\pi}{6}$